# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY yo@>=1.0.0

Tags: generator, yeoman

### Can somebody give me a hand with yeoman, angular generator and the shown dependency problem?

When updating any generator I am getting this issue marked in red. Below in the image.
 Tried with Angular, Polymer, Bootstrap, Mobile, Webapp and Karma generators, but always with the same result.

[image]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>yo --version && echo %PATH% %NODE_PATH% && node -e "console.log(process.platform, process.versions)" && type Gruntfile.js
    1.8.5
    C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Ruby22\bin;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin %NODE_PATH%
    win32 { http_parser: '2.7.0',
    node: '6.6.0',
    v8: '5.1.281.83',
    uv: '1.9.1',
    zlib: '1.2.8',
    ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
    icu: '57.1',
    modules: '48',
    openssl: '1.0.2h' }
    // Generated on 2016-09-21 using generator-angular 0.15.1
    'use strict';

    // # Globbing
    // for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
    // 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
    // use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
    // 'test/spec/**/*.js'

    module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
        useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
        ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
        cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn'
    });

    // Configurable paths for the application
    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: appConfig,

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jscs:all'],
            options: {
            livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
        },
        jsTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'newer:jscs:test', 'karma']
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'postcss:server']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
            livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: 'localhost',
            livereload: 35729
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
            open: true,
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                connect.static('.tmp'),
                connect().use(
                    '/bower_components',
                    connect.static('./bower_components')
                ),
                connect().use(
                    '/app/styles',
                    connect.static('./app/styles')
                ),
                connect.static(appConfig.app)
                ];
            }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
            port: 9001,
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                connect.static('.tmp'),
                connect.static('test'),
                connect().use(
                    '/bower_components',
                    connect.static('./bower_components')
                ),
                connect.static(appConfig.app)
                ];
            }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
            open: true,
            base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        }
        },

        // Make sure there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        test: {
            options: {
            jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
        }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par
        jscs: {
        options: {
            config: '.jscsrc',
            verbose: true
        },
        all: {
            src: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        test: {
            src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
        }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
            dot: true,
            src: [
                '.tmp',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
            ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        postcss: {
        options: {
            processors: [
            require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: ['last 1 version']})
            ]
        },
        server: {
            options: {
            map: true
            },
            files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
            ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
        },
        test: {
            devDependencies: true,
            src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
            ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
            fileTypes:{
            js: {
                block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
                detect: {
                    js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                },
                replace: {
                    js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
                }
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
        }
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: './bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false,
            raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
            generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
            sourcemap: true
            }
        }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        filerev: {
        dist: {
            src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
        }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
            html: {
                steps: {
                js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                css: ['cssmin']
                },
                post: {}
            }
            }
        }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        options: {
            assetsDirs: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
            ],
            patterns: {
            js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
            }
        }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //   dist: {}
        // },

        imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
        },

        svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            src: '{,*/}*.svg',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
        },

        htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            conservativeCollapse: true,
            collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
            removeCommentsFromCDATA: true
            },
            files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            src: ['*.html'],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
        },

        ngtemplates: {
        dist: {
            options: {
            module: 'system32App',
            htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
            usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js'
            },
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: 'views/{,*/}*.html',
            dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
        }
        },

        // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
        // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
        ngAnnotate: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
            src: '*.js',
            dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
            }]
        }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
        dist: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            src: [
                '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                '*.html',
                'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
            ]
            }, {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp/images',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
            src: ['generated/*']
            }, {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.',
            src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass:server'
        ],
        test: [
            'compass'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass:dist',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
        },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
        unit: {
            configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:server',
        'postcss:server',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:test',
        'postcss',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'postcss',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'newer:jscs',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peer dependencies aren’t installed any longer with npm since version 3. The authors of that generators just haven’t updated their package.json files.
Plus npm 3 still throw warnings. But you can simply ignore them.

See https://twitter.com/Vaxilart/status/666698958975148033 for reference. This answer is from one of the creators of the yeoman eco system.